# errorlevel with psexec and netuser

Tags: batch-file

Here is my script. The issue I'm having is that it just basically ignores my "if errorlevel" I tried the various different ways

```
for /f %%F in (C:\IPLIST.txt) do (
pstools\psexec.exe \\%%F -u administrator -p password net user administrator password1
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 goto two
:two
pstools\psexec.exe \\%%F -u administrator -p password3 net user administrator password2
)
```

So it goes through the txt file list of IP addresses and it changes the local admin password. those 2 commands are to give it different authentication credentials, now I know I can do this with pspasswd but the "-u -p" switches wont work. but this works.. its just if the first command succeeds and exits with errorcode 0 it still runs the second command for the same IP. I want it to ignore the second command for that IP if the first one succeeds. and just continue down the list..

Is this because I'm using net user or pstools thats why its ignoring it?

Comment: You cannot use a GOTO in the middle of a FOR block.  It breaks the FOR command.

Comment: Not understanding your problem with using PSPASSWD.  It should work just fine.

Comment: so is there a work around to use the goto command in a for loop?

Comment: Would it not be more logical to run PSEXEC when your IF command is TRUE instead of trying to use GOTO.

Comment: how would i do that? the reason for the 2 commands is because i need to provide 2-3 credentials to use for authenticating.

Comment: Have you used `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and `if !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0`?

Comment: Even if the `goto` would work within `()`; it does not make any sense to jump to the next line, this happens anyway...

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for /f %%F in (C:\IPLIST.txt) do (
    pstools\psexec.exe \\%%F -u administrator -p password net user administrator password1
    if errorlevel 1 pstools\psexec.exe \\%%F -u administrator -p password3 net user administrator password2
    if errorlevel 1 pstools\psexec.exe \\%%F -u administrator -p password5 net user administrator password5
    echo Rinse and Repeat
)
```

Comment: This not works. `%errorlevel%` is inside a code block, so it would require delayed expansion. It is simpler to just use `if errorlevel 1` that is equivalent to "if %errorlevel% is greater than 0" (if pstools just return positive errorlevel values)

Comment: @Aacini, thanks.  Was not thinking when I wrote that!

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%F in (C:\IPLIST.txt) do (
    pstools\psexec.exe \%%F -u administrator -p password net user administrator password1
    if !errorlevel! NEQ 0 pstools\psexec.exe \%%F -u administrator -p password3 net user administrator password2
)
```

this works. answered my question. thank you